# VSTS YAML Build publishing strange path

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm `publish`ing build artefacts from `$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/cookiecutter.utility.tool.csproj` and setting an output path of `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/dist`, however for some reason I can't comprehend it's adding the `src` element to the output path, rather than just `dist`.

I've checked the YAML docs and can't see anything that would suggest I've done something wrong.

[image: Artefact explorer showing publlish output]

### The YAML section

```
 task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Publish
    inputs:
      command: publish
      publishWebProjects: false
      zipAfterPublish: false
      projects: $(projectDir)/cookiecutter.utility.tool.csproj
      arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) --self-contained -r win10-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true  /p:PublishTrimmed=true
'
```

### View of source repo.

[image: Repo View]

Comment: Just wanted to check in after the weekend what the status on this issue was? Does below explanation and verified way can solve what's your puzzle?

Comment: Oh you are a good egg! We've had Christmas break over here, so haven't had chance to check... I'll check shortly as I'm heading to the office.

Comment: aha~ hope I did not disturb your break. Just enjoy the holiday and forget these:-) haha

Answer (score 1):

Because you specify the `projects` in the `dotnet publish` task.

This `.csproj` is what you are trying to publish. When you specify the exactly project file value to task parameter `projects` , at this time, the output path is in `project file’s directory` rather than the `root directory`. That's why it keep the path of `src` in the artifact path.

If you don't want this src displayed, just remove `projects: $(projectDir)/cookiecutter.utility.tool.csproj` . Then the `publish` will work with the root directory(all projects) and the `src` will not displayed any more.

---

**Update:**

As I mentioned in my comment, as normal, it will looking for project file automatically under its working directory during `dotnet.exe` execution. For VSTS, the default working directory is solution folder (root).

So, to work around the `Specify a project or solution file` error and avoid the strange path added in artifact also, you can configure yourself working directory by using `workingDirectory: src`.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) --self-contained -r win10-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true  /p:PublishTrimmed=true'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: true
    workingDirectory: src
```

This could let you avoid the `src` display in artifact structure without error.

[image]

Comment: No joy on that one - `MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.`

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar, you removed the `projects` specified in **dotnet test** task and faced this error? Based on what I know, for dotnet test, project file is not a necessary argument, this error is very stranged. This is my artifact with specify the projects: https://dev.azure.com/ForMerlin/dotnet/_build/results?buildId=1441&view=artifacts&type=publishedArtifacts and this is not specified: https://dev.azure.com/ForMerlin/dotnet/_build/results?buildId=1442&view=artifacts&type=publishedArtifacts

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar. This is my build definition which artifacts structure **does not contain** the strange path such as the `src` or `s` https://imgur.com/a/FzfVQFr

Comment: How strange? I removed it from publish path, which now matches yours

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar, yes, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet), as normal, projects is a optional argument which is not necessary one that you must specify it in task. Let me guess, there's no .csproj files located under your **root directory**, right? Like this one: https://imgur.com/a/t5FblDU . The csproj files are all located in second level of directory?

Comment: Correct! Nothing at top level

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar, when applying the `dotnet publish`, it will firstly search the project file under its workspace, if does not found it, it will prompt the error message you mentioned in the first comment. In your scenario, you'd better specify the `projects` to let `dotnet.exe` know project file location.  At this time, `src` would not be avoided because it is publishing under the project file which contains the `src` instead of root path.

Comment: So there is no way around it? It's not an issue, I can just change my release pipelines path.

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar Could you give me a screenshots of your reos structure? Then I can reproduce a similar structure on my side and try to find the work around to avoid this strange path successfully.

Comment: Updated - I've added the of the source repo.

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar, Got the work around now, you can see  my update in the answer.